# Пробую запустить бота Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пробую запустить дефолтнейшего бота в новом окружении (пробовал и conda и pip) из самого первого гайда груши. Получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/tg-bot/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
..............................................................................................
  File "/home/ubuntu/tg-bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_core_utils.py", line 515, in count_refs
    recurse(state['definitions'][ref], count_refs)
KeyError: 'aiogram.types.input_text_message_content.InputTextMessageContent:23166832'
```

Вообще не понял, все сделал по гайду, версия питона менял 3.9-3.11, версия aiogram 3.0.0.
Помогите я вроде не впервые этим занимаюсь...

Comment: Покажите ваш код?

Comment: Попробуйте установить нужные пакеты глобально и запустить тот же код. Если поможет, то проблема с виртуальным окружением, если нет, то либо в коде, либо в модуле (но это вряд ли)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это баг в самой библиотеке aiogram. А точнее баги в совместимости разных версий библиотек aiogram и pydantic.

Выходы из ситуации:

- установить aiogram более новой версии -- v3.1.1 (в ней несовместимость исправлена)
- установить pydantic более старой версии -- v2.3.0